# ViewPager2 переменная на все фрагменты

Tags: android, android-studio

с помощью ViewPager2 вывожу на экран слайдер из нескольких разных фрагментов (точное количество их заранее не известно).
В первом фрагменте мне нужно в переменную внести значение. В остальных фрагментах нужен доступ к значению этой переменной.
Подскажите можно ли как-то объявить такую переменную. Пробовал объявить в FragmentStateAdapter  public Integer ExcelDocID=0;, но в самих фрагментах она не видна. Или нужно смотреть в сторону передачи параметров между фрагментами?

```
                       ViewPager2 pager = findViewById(R.id.ExcelViewPager2);
                        FragmentStateAdapter pageAdapter = new ZZMyAdapter(this);
                        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
                    }
                }
           }


    private class ZZMyAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
       // public Integer ExcelDocID=0;
public ZZMyAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
            super(fragmentActivity);
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            if (position==0) {
                FragmentExcelDoctor ffff1 = new FragmentExcelDoctor();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                String[] row=rowList.get(position);
                args.putString("param1", row[0].trim());
                ffff1.setArguments(args);
                return ffff1;
            }else
            if (position>0&&position<PAGE_COUNT) {
                String[] row=rowList.get(position);
                FragmentExcelPacient ffff2 = new FragmentExcelPacient();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("param1", row[0]);
                args.putString("param2", row[1]);
                args.putString("param3", row[2]);
                args.putString("param4", row[3]);
                args.putString("param5", row[4]);
                ffff2.setArguments(args);
                return ffff2;
            }else return null;
        }
       @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Неизвестно что там у вас за переменная и условия сохранения её значения в зависимости от жизненного цикла приложения, активности, фрагментов. Варианты: [Shared `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing), преференсы, упомянутая передача в аргументах, просто `public static` поле, синглтон, ...

Comment: спасибо.  Пробовал объявить в FragmentStateAdapter public Integer ExcelDocID=0;, но в самих фрагментах она не видна. Сделаю через преференс, но по ощущениям костыль :))))

Comment: Преференс сохраняет данные в ПЗУ - оно вам надо?

Comment: Вы можете определить что то общее для всех фрагментов и записывать туда переменную, к примеру если все фрагменты происходят из одной активности то и записывать в нее. А после что то вроде 
 `((MainActivity) getActivity()).param1` ну и можно проверку `if(getActivity() instanceof MainActivity)`

Comment: Через переменную в активити не получилось получить доступ, надо посидеть подумать, что я неправильно делаю. да с преференс сразу не понравилось мне. в активити сделал textview c visibility=gone. а из фрагментов к нему доступ есть, можно и читать и писать.   ExelDocIDTextView01=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ExelDocIDTextView);

Comment: да еще вариант рабочий: в активити  public static String aaa="1111";   во фрагменте можно прочитать   String bbb= MainActivity.aaa;    Только не понял почему работает только с переменной  static